# Sitecore 7.5 and Adobe IFilter 11 not working

Tags: indexing, sitecore, sitecore7, ifilter, sitecore-media-library

I am getting the following error when I am trying to plug Sitecore 7.5 and Adobe Ifilter 11 (64bit) apparently Ifilter 9 is working with sitecore 7x but Adobe removed the link to download it...
that's the error that I am getting....
I have added the Ifilter path to the environment variables & I have been playing with security but I am always getting the same error, guess that I am missing some registry permissions...
I am just curious to know how other people solved the problem using Ifilter and the new Sitecore computed fields and sitecore reccomendation to index PDF content....

this is my error:

ManagedPoolThread #4 17:17:35 ERROR Could not compute value for ComputedIndexField: _content for indexable: sitecore://master/{7E5F66DF-2A4E-448F-B8DF-656BE6D4DA19}?lang=en&ver=1
Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Message: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Extracters.IFilterTextExtraction.IClassFactory.CreateInstance(Object pUnkOuter, Guid& refiid, Object& ppunk)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Extracters.IFilterTextExtraction.FilterLoader.LoadFilterFromDll(String dllName, String filterPersistClass)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Extracters.IFilterTextExtraction.FilterLoader.LoadAndInitIFilter(String fileName, String extension)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Extracters.IFilterTextExtraction.FilterReader..ctor(String fileName)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemIFilterTextExtractor.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneDocumentBuilder.AddComputedIndexFields()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stelio,

There are a lot of people with this issue with Adobe's iFilter.  The thought is it comes down the permissions required to run the iFilter.  Sitecore support's official answer on this can be found in this similar SO answer -> [Sitecore 7 pdf indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998725/sitecore-7-pdf-indexing)

However I still had issues with Adobe's iFilter after following these steps, as well as steps outlined in this blog post -> http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/06/Why-does-my-IFilter-not-work.aspx

After troubleshooting for quite a while on this I did finally find a combination that worked, but then we started having the Adobe iFilter crash on a number of PDF files. Knowing newer versions of Adobe's iFilter have even more challenges we just opted to purchase FoxIt's PDF IFilter (http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/ifilter/) which is faster and much more reliable.  Have not had any issues with it up to this point.

The cost can be somewhat significant if you are using Lucene and are relying on your Content Delivery servers to build their caches since you will need a license for each server.  If you are using SOLR or a dedicated crawling server you should only need licenses for the server building the indexes.

Comment: Matt, thanks for answering, most of the links point to the version 9 of the Ifilter and it says that it does not work on the following versions and I was not able to find on line Ifilter 9... So I guess that the only choice is to go with a custom Ifilter for Pdf indexing or build your custom one (not a great option neither...)

Comment: Stelio, wish I had a better answer for you.

Comment: I found a DL link to Adobe that worked for me to grab iFilter 9. I know this question is old, but others might come across it like I did. It's 64bit v9: http://download.adobe.com/pub/adobe/acrobat/win/9.x/PDFiFilter64installer.zip